# NodeJS unit testing of database routines using callbacks

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unit-testing, mocha.js, nodeunit

Here is the problem: I have class WPSManager, which is exported as a module:

```js
function WPSManager(dbclient) {
 var databaseclient = dbclient;

 this.getWrappers = function(excludeid, callback) {
  var query = "SELECT * FROM public.wps_methods WHERE id <> " + excludeid + " AND id > 88;";

  databaseclient.query(query, function(error, rows, fields) {
   callback(rows.rows);
  });
 } //end getWrappers()
} //end class

module.exports = WPSManager;
```

How can I test results of the query? I've tried variant with **nodeunit** (providing assertions in callback for `getWrappers()`), also the variant with **mocha** (example below). All of them are not making any assertions in the callback that I provide.

```js
delete require.cache;
var assert     = require("assert");
var pg         = require("pg");
var WPSManager = require("./WPSManager");

/**
 * Database client initiation.
 */

var dbclient = new pg.Client("***");
dbclient.connect();
 
describe('WPSManager', function(){
  describe('getWrappers()', function(){
    it('should return list of wrappers', function(){
   var wpsmanager = new WPSManager(dbclient);

   wpsmanager.getWrappers(14, function(data) {
     // This assertion is not performed
        assert.equal(5, data.length);
  done();
   }); 
    })
  })
});
```

So, here is the question - do any of unit testing tools for NodeJS can solve this question, or only thing that is available - using **assert()**? Assert is great, but it is not so fancy:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jasmine-node (2.0.0) I would something like the below.
I mocked your DB, but it should work with the real thing too.

```
function WPSManager(dbclient) {
    var databaseclient = dbclient;

    this.getWrappers = function(excludeid, callback) {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM public.wps_methods WHERE id <> " + excludeid + " AND id > 88;";

        databaseclient.query(query, function(error, rows, fields) {
            callback(rows.rows);
        });
    } //end getWrappers()
} //end class

var dbclient = { 
    query : function ( query, callback ) {
        setTimeout( function () {
            callback( null, { rows:Array(5) }, null );
        }, 500);
    }
};

//var dbclient = mockDB;
//var dbclient = new pg.Client("***");
//dbclient.connect();

describe('WPSManager', function(){
    describe('getWrappers()', function(){
        it('should return list of wrappers', function (done) {

            var wpsmanager  = new WPSManager(dbclient);

            wpsmanager.getWrappers(14, function(data) {
                expect(data.length).toBe(5);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling about mocking technique! I'll definitely use it, when working with the database will get too messy:) Anyway, Jasmine helped - it is able to catch it's own assertions in the asynchronous code, so it perfectly suits me. Also it is good because of easy integration with other code-quality tools.